# swift pdf file not attaching to an email

Tags: swift, pdf, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have the below code which is suppose to attach a file named "file.pdf" which was created and placed into the temp directory as such

```
pdfFileUrl = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())file.pdf"
```

But the email does not have my attachment as I am expecting it to

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {

    createReportPDF()

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
        mail.setToRecipients(["dpreston10@gmail.com"])
        mail.setMessageBody("<p>You're so awesome!</p>", isHTML: true)
        if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(pdfFileUrl, ofType: "pdf") {
            print("File path loaded.")

            if let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
                print("File data loaded.")
                mail.addAttachmentData(fileData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "file.pdf")
            }
        }

        presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // show failure alert
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see as far as the log output? I'm just trying to determine where the logic might be potentially wrong.

Comment: Neither of my print statements are printed. so it looks like the if let filePath is failing..not sure why

Comment: What sort of format is your `pdfFileUrl` in? Can you print it out here?

Comment: Running in a simulator it looks like this

/Users/dpreston10/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/40DD5B0A-6168-4F2E-A220-D9DEE50FEFDA/data/Containers/Data/Application/C8F3E51D-479D-463B-A7DF-C1CCCB57A970/tmp/file.pdf

Comment: How do temporary files get deleted in an app? Does this happen on its own over time or does the developer need to account for the deletion?

Comment: @ddpishere can you share your `createReportPDF()` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your file is put into the user's temporary folder, I do not think it will be accessible from the a `NSBundle` method. That said, if you are writing the `NSData` to disk in the temporary folder and then directly emailing it, you may want to consider just passing that variable (`pdfData`) to the mail controller like:

```
mail.addAttachmentData(pdfData, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: "file.pdf")
```

Comment: no the pdf file is generated as part of the app and is not bundled. it is saved in the temp folder. I am able to view the pdf so i know its is there

Comment: Can you post the code that comes up with the variable `pdfFileUrl`?

Comment: Sure it is 
`pdfFileUrl = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())file.pdf"`
        `pdfData.writeToFile(pdfFileUrl, atomically: true)`

Comment: i commented out the `if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(pdfFileUrl, ofType: "pdf") {` and it worked like a champ...would love to know what the issues is in that line but i'll move on for now as I know the file exists at that point..but still

Comment: I've updated my solution to hopefully reflect your comments.

Comment: How do temporary files get deleted in an app? Does this happen on its own over time or does the developer need to account for the deletion?